# How to retrieve an offset from a past event? Pine Script V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

`SomethingHappens[0]` happens in the present so it happens at same candle as `close[0]`.

But `SomethingHappens[1]` (if I'm not wrong that we can address events in a series this way) happened in the time of `close[x]`  where `x` is anything, e.g. `2`, `3` … `29` …, etc. – it changes all the time as the chart flows. We want to know what's that `x` in this `close[x]` to address the candle of that `SomethingHappens[1]`.

Is there a way to retrieve that offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you can use `ta.barssince()` for this.

```
x = ta.barssince(SomethingHappens)
```